# Extension on the rust textbook's guessing game is showing odd behavior

Tags: rust

So I'm extending the guessing game to basically ask the user if they want to play again. If they type `y`, the program will return to the main game loop and if they type `n`, it just breaks out of the current loop and the program ends. If they type anything else, in theory it should just jump to the top of the `play_again` loop and reassign the `yae_or_nay` variable as whatever the player inputs next. But it doesn't do that, or at least it looks like it overwrites it incorrectly. Am I reassigning the variable incorrectly? Heres the code (note that the first half of the program is almost the same as in the textbook, but since the program is so short I just decided to include the whole thing):

```
extern crate rand;

use std::io;
use std::cmp::Ordering;
use rand::Rng; // random number generation library from rand 

fn main() {
println!("Guessing game!\n");

let mut answer = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1,101); 
'gameloop: loop {
    println!("Please print your guess:");

    let mut yae_or_nay = String::new();
    let mut guess = String::new();

    io::stdin().read_line(&mut guess)
        .expect("Failed to read line");

    let guess : u32 = match guess.trim().parse() {
        Ok(num) => num,
        Err(_) => {
            println!("Not a number!");
            continue;
        }
    };

    match guess.cmp(&answer) {
        Ordering::Less => println!("Higher!"),
        Ordering::Greater => println!("Lower!"),
        Ordering::Equal => {
            println!("Correct! Would you like to play again? (y/n)");
            'play_again: loop {
                io::stdin().read_line(&mut yae_or_nay)
                    .expect("Failed to read line.");

                match yae_or_nay.trim() { // match against a string
                    "y" => {
                        answer = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1,101);
                        println!("Playing again...");
                        continue 'gameloop;
                    },
                    "n" => {
                        println!("Thanks for playing! Exiting now.");
                        break
                    },
                    _ => {
                        println!("what? You entered {}", &yae_or_nay);
                        continue 'play_again
                    }
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

And here's a snippet of the console output:

```
46
Correct! Would you like to play again? (y/n)
i
what? You entered i

y
what? You entered i
y

n
what? You entered i
y
n

 . // period here for formatting sake, not actually in console
```

As you can see, the way my program is reassigning `yae_or_nay` seems pretty strange. Anyone know what's going on? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you never clear `yae_or_nay`, and [`io::stdin().read_line(&mut yae_or_nay)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Stdin.html#method.read_line) will [*append*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.read_line) to the string, not replace its content.

> Read all bytes until a newline (the 0xA byte) is reached, and append them to the provided buffer.

Either you should do

```
yae_or_nay.clear();
```

before you read into it, or likely better would be to move the declaration to

```
'play_again: loop {
    let mut yae_or_nay = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut yae_or_nay)
        .expect("Failed to read line.");
```

Comment: Oh thanks! The textbook has yet to teach me about clear. I guess that's what I get for experimentation. Why would moving the declaration like that be better though?

Comment: @awallace04 Moving the `String::new();` inside the loop means that you create a new string every time the `'play_again` loop restarts. Your current code never creates a new string, so `read_line` will just keep adding on to the end of the `String`.

Comment: oh I understand that, I mean what makes moving `String::new();` into the loop better than just calling `clear()`?

Comment: It's different tradeoffs. Code is generally easier to read when all the pieces for a particular operation are localized to a small area, which is why I'd favor moving the declaration. `.clear` would be beneficial if performance were a concern and you wanted to avoid reallocating the string on every iteration, but that is absolutely unimportant here.

Comment: " better would be to move the declaration to" in this context better is very opinion oriented, unless you move the string somewhere `clear` is much more idiomatic when you just want to discard and reuse the buffer. So "better" is a bit wrong here.

Comment: @Stargateur On the other hand, it's also idiomatic (and just a good idea in general) to minimize the scope of all variables, precisely to avoid accidental reuse (of which this is an example).

Comment: Thanks both of you!

Comment: @awallace04 Please mark the question as answered if you're satisfied.